# What is the moment generating function of product of chi-squared distributions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent Gaussian random variables, i.e.,  $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1), Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. How can we calculate the following moment generating function,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left[\exp(tX^2Y^2) \right].
\end{align}
I do some simulations, and find that $t\le0.01$ can guarantee the existence of the expectation.

Comment: Have you tried to compute it by hand?

Comment: I think $t\le0$ is needed. Mathematica gives $$\frac{\mathrm e^{-\frac{1}{8 t}} K_0(-\frac{1}{8 t})}{2\sqrt{-t\pi}}$$ where $K_0$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).